# Fade in and out using CSS on javascript multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, css, fade

On my website I have two links, if you click on portfolio, the div portfolio becomes visible.

I use this code to switch between them `<a href="" onclick="return show('portfolio','profile');">`

How can I make a quick fade-in-out between the divs using CSS?
Visit my site [here](https://joexn.com) and you'll see.

Comment: Kindly don't vandalize.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by vandalize.

Comment: Don't edit the post like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small demo for you to look at and have an idea of what AlexG is suggesting in Option 1 using CSS Animations (and jQuery).

---

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/1w12j608/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
var vHome = $("#home"),
  vPortfolio = $("#portfolio"),
  bTriggerHome = $("#trigger-home"),
  bTriggerPortfolio = $("#trigger-portfolio");

function switchView() {
  vHome.add(vPortfolio).toggleClass("hide-view");
};

bTriggerHome.add(bTriggerPortfolio).on("click", function() {
  switchView();
});
```

```css
#home,
#portfolio {
  height: 500px;
  animation: fadeInUp 1s both;
}
#home {
  background-color: tomato;
}
#portfolio {
  background-color: royalblue;
}
.hide-view {
  display: none;
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0)
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home">
  <button id="trigger-portfolio">
    Switch View
  </button>
</div>

<div id="portfolio" class="hide-view">
  <button id="trigger-home">
    Switch View
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You set your invisible divs to display: none. Thus, standard CSS transitions won't work out of the box.

display: none is a good idea because the browser won't spend time rendering that markup at all. However, CSS transitions need a hack to work with an element that move from display: none to display: !none, so you have two options:

1) Just use CSS Animations instead; add/remove a class to the elements that contain a CSS animation definition and it will play straight away.

2) Set your invisible divs to height: 0 and opacity: 0; and transition to opacity: 1 using a regular CSS transition (often triggered by a class change)